# PostGIS: ST_Transform error

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, srid

I have a table (`tbl1`) containing POINT geometries in EPSG:27700 (British National Grid).

```
SELECT id, ST_AsText(geom) as geom FROM tbl1;
```

=

```
  id  | geom
------+--------
    1 | POINT(363179.79 176400.12)      
    2 | POINT(333743.58 159668.54)     
    3 | POINT(375287 162596) 
    4 | POINT(340283.42 172058.76)
```

However I receive an error when I try to transform the CRS to 3857 (or 4326). Example:

```
SELECT ST_TRANSFORM(geom, 3857) as geom
FROM tbl1;
```

or

```
SELECT ST_TRANSFORM(ST_SetSRID(geom, 27700), 3857) as geom
FROM tbl1;
```

Both result in this error:

```
ERROR:  could not form projection (PJ) from 'srid=27700' to 'srid=3857'
SQL state: XX000
```

Additional context:

PostgreSQL version: 13

PostGIS version:

```
SELECT postgis_full_version();
```

=

```
POSTGIS="3.1.1 3.1.1" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.1" SFCGAL="1.3.8" PROJ="7.1.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.2.1, released 2020/12/29 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

There are other similar questions on GIS SE but none with answers or as detailed as this.

Comment: I believe the key is in `GDAL_DATA not found` returned by your query `SELECT postgis_full_version();`.

Comment: thanks. I have GDAL 3.2.2 installed on my machine however. Perhaps the PostgreSQL installation isn't using it...

Comment: I can't say why but GDAL_DATA is not set correctly for your PostGIS.